# Nested Loop not firing events in the knockout js

Tags: knockout.js

I am using nested for each to display reviews for each Product using knock.  My requirement, i need to open a modal popup to display the reviews of each product in the model popup.

Model popup contains radio button. Based on the selection of the radio button i need to `show (VisibleText,VisibleField) or hide (VisibleText,VisibleField)`

Similar I need to show `VisiblePage` based  on the selection of the checkbox. I have written the events methods that it should work based on the each Product. Please help as the events are not firing and working properly in the nested loop.

Please see the attached screenshot if it is `viewable`

```
    <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="TestApplication.WebForm1" %>

    <!DOCTYPE html>

    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head runat="server">
        <title></title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-3.1.1.js">
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/knockout-3.4.2.js"></script>
        <script src="Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
        <link href="Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function ProductVM() {
                self = this;
                self.Products = ko.observableArray([]);
                self.show = ko.observable(false);

                function addProduct(productId, productName, reviews) {
                    return {
                        ProductId: ko.observable(productId),
                        ProductName: ko.observable(productName),
                        Reviews: ko.observableArray([reviews])
                    }
                }

                function addReviews(stock, page, visibleStock, visibleOutStock, visiblePage, show) {
                    return {
                        FieldType: ko.observable(stock),
                        PageType: ko.observable(page),
                        VisibleText: ko.observable(visibleStock),
                        VisibleField: ko.observable(visibleOutStock),
                        VisiblePage: ko.observable(visiblePage),
                        Show :ko.observable(show)
                    }
                }

                var data = {
                    Products: [
                      {
                          "ProductId": 1,
                          "ProductName": "Guitar",
                          "Reviews": [{
                              "FieldType": 1,
                              "PageType": 2,
                              "VisibleText": 3,
                              "VisibleField": 4,
                              "VisiblePage": 5,
                              "show" : false
                          }]
                      },
                      {
                          "ProductId": 2,
                          "ProductName": "Paino",
                          "Reviews": [{
                              "FieldType": 1,
                              "Page": 2,
                              "VisibleText": 3,
                              "VisibleField": 4,
                              "VisiblePage": 5,
                              "show" : false
                          }]
                      }
                    ]
                }
                console.log(data);

                for (var i = 0; i < data.Products.length; i++) {
                    var p1 = data.Products[i].ProductId;
                    var p2 = data.Products[i].ProductName;
                    var r3 = data.Products[i].Reviews;

                    var reviewObj = '';
                    for (j = 0; j < r3.length; j++) {
                        reviewObj = new addReviews(r3[j].FieldType, r3[j].PageType, r3[j].VisibleText, r3[j].VisibleField, r3[j].VisiblePage);
                    }
                    self.Products.push(new addProduct(p1, p2, reviewObj));
                }
                console.log(self.Products())
            }

            self.FreeTypeChanged = function () {
                self.VisibleText(true);
                self.VisibleField(false);
            };

            self.FieldTypeChanged = function () {
                self.VisibleField(true);
                self.VisibleText(false);
            };

            self.pageSelectionChanged = function () {
                var result = $('#checkPage').prop('checked');
                if (result == true) {
                    self.VisiblePage(true);
                }
                else {
                    self.VisiblePage(false);
                }

            };
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="form1" runat="server">
            <div>
                <table>
                    <thead></thead>
                    <tbody data-bind="foreach: Products">
                        <tr>
                            <td><span data-bind="text: ProductId"></span></td>
                            <td><span data-bind="text: ProductName"></span></td>
                            <td><a id="openModal" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#testModal">
                                <span class="fa fa-folder-o">Open Modal</span>
                            </a></td>
                            <td>
                                <table>
                                    <tbody data-bind="foreach: Reviews">                                  
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                            <div class="modal fade" id="testModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" data-bind="enable: Show"  >
                                                <div class="modal-dialog" role="document" style="width: 100%; align-self: center;">
                                                    <div class="modal-content">
                                                        <div class="modal-header" style="text-align: left">
                                                            Select Field Value
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="modal-body" id="selectorViewBody">
                                                            <div class="container">
                                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                                    <label class="radio-inline">
                                                                        <input type="radio" class="radio" value="FreeText" data-bind="checked: FieldType, event: { change: $parent.FreeTypeChanged }"
                                                                            name="modelSelection" />
                                                                        FreeText                   
                                                                    </label>
                                                                    <label class="radio-inline">
                                                                        <input type="radio" class="radio" value="Field" data-bind="checked: FieldType, event: { change: FieldTypeChanged }"
                                                                            name="modelSelection" />
                                                                        Field</label>
                                                                </div>
                                                                <div class="form-group" data-bind="visible: VisibleText">
                                                                    <input type="text" id="txtFreeTextName" class="form-control" />
                                                                </div>
                                                                <div class="form-group" data-bind="visible: VisibleField">
                                                                    <div class="row">
                                                                        <div class="col-md-4">
                                                                            <label for="ddlModuleNames" class="control-label">Domain (Module) :</label>
                                                                            <select class="form-control" name="ddlModuleNames" data-bind="options: '1 2 3 4', optionsCaption: '--Select Table Names --'"></select>
                                                                        </div>
                                                                        <div class="col-md-4">
                                                                            <label for="ddlModuleNames" class="control-label">Field Name :</label>
                                                                            <select class="form-control" name="ddlFieldNames" data-bind="options:'1 2 3 4', optionsCaption: '--Select Table Names --'"></select>
                                                                        </div>
                                                                    </div>
                                                                    <div class="row">
                                                                        <div class="col-md-8">
                                                                            <label>
                                                                                <input type="checkbox" class="check" id="checkPage" data-bind="checked: PageType, event: { change: pageSelectionChanged }"
                                                                                    name="pageSelection" />
                                                                                Show Page/Row</label>
                                                                        </div>
                                                                    </div>
                                                                </div>
                                                                <div class="form-group" data-bind="visible: VisiblePage">
                                                                    <div class="row">
                                                                        <div class="col-md-4">
                                                                            <label for="txtPage" class="control-label">Page</label>
                                                                            <input type="text" id="txtPage" class="form-control" />
                                                                        </div>
                                                                        <div class="col-md-4">
                                                                            <label for="txtRow" class="control-label">Row</label>
                                                                            <input type="text" id="txtRow" class="form-control" />
                                                                        </div>
                                                                    </div>
                                                                </div>
                                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                                    <button class="btn btn-primary " type="submit">Submit</button>
                                                                    <button class="btn btn-primary " type="submit">Cancel</button>
                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                                </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
            <script>
                $(document).ready(function () {
                    ko.applyBindings(new ProductVM());
                })
            </script>


        </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are not adding reviews, try and change add product as follow

```
 function addProduct(productId, productName, reviews) {
          return {
            ProductId: ko.observable(productId),
            ProductName: ko.observable(productName),
            Reviews : ko.observableArray(reviews)
          }
        }
```